# Растет нагрузка базой mariadb и load average достигает до 30-40

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, mariadb, highload

Всем привет. 
В наличии есть сервер с 8-ми ядерным CPU, RAM 32GB, 2 SSD RAID 1 (mdadm, lvm), Centos 7. 
База данных: 10.3.16-MariaDB.  На сервере крутится проект на Битрикс.

Средняя нагрузка на базу от 1 до 4 тыс. запросов в секунду. С такой нагрузкой сервер работал ~4 мес. и load average сервера составлял порядка 0.7-2. Нагрузка mysqld составляла от 50% до 200%.

**Но что-то пошло не так**, производительность начала резко деградировать. 
Сейчас демон базы грузит систему по top на 400-600%, а load average достигает 40. И такой load average может быть и при 400% и при 600% нагрузки даваемой mysqld.

По наблюдениям бывают моменты и производительность возвращается не надолго. При равных метриках базы данных по кол. запросов нагрузка может на какое-то время прийти в норму до load average: 1-2.

Перезагрузка сервера или mysqld не дает ни какого эффекта.

Потратил несколько дней в поисках связи метрик базы данных и операционной системы в целях найти связь в отклонениях, но пока не смог.

Теоретически это может быть даже не база данных, железо или еще что-то.

Изначально подумал, что возможно что-то не так с дисками, но trim включен, по данным atop дисковая система нагружена на 3-7%.

Модель SSD дисков
    Model Family:     Intel S4510/S4610/S4500/S4600 Series SSDs
    Device Model:     INTEL SSDSC2KB240G8

Данные мониторинга за disk latency

```
Read: sda   min: 0.13 ms,   max: 30.04 ms, avg: 0.66 ms
Read: sdb   min: 0.01 ms,   max: 27.37 ms, avg: 0.90 ms
Write: sda  min: 0.09 ms,   max: 8.33 ms,   avg: 1.34 ms
Write: sdb  min: 0.09 ms,   max: 10.48 ms,  avg: 1.41 ms
```

[image]

Настройки базы

```
[mysqld]
key-buffer-size = 32M
long_query_time=1
performance_schema=on
read_rnd_buffer_size=128K
sort_buffer_size=1M
read_buffer_size=128K
join_buffer_size=512K
max_allowed_packet=64M
sql_mode=
transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED
innodb_io_capacity = 3000
innodb_io_capacity_max = 6000
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
innodb_thread_concurrency=10
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100
open_files_limit = 65535
table_open_cache=5000
query_cache_min_res_unit=3000
thread_cache_size=500
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_log_buffer_size=12M
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_size=128M
query_cache_limit=1M
query_cache_min_res_unit=3500
tmp_table_size=1024M
max_heap_table_size=1024M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=15G
innodb_log_file_size=1G
innodb_log_files_in_group=3
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=15
```

Лимиты системы ulimit -a

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 127750
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 65535
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 65535
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS

```
=====================================
2019-07-30 06:57:50 0x7f9e40f63700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 1 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 1621 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 1 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 1622
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 320574
--Thread 140317647853312 has waited at btr0sea.cc line 1476 for 0.00 seconds the semaphore:
X-lock (wait_ex) on RW-latch at 0x55fd09116700 created in file btr0sea.cc line 243
a writer (thread id 140317647853312) has reserved it in mode  wait exclusive
number of readers 1, waiters flag 1, lock_word: ffffffff
Last time write locked in file btr0sea.cc line 1557
--Thread 140317668058880 has waited at btr0sea.cc line 934 for 0.00 seconds the semaphore:
S-lock on RW-latch at 0x55fd09116700 created in file btr0sea.cc line 243
a writer (thread id 140317647853312) has reserved it in mode  wait exclusive
number of readers 1, waiters flag 1, lock_word: ffffffff
Last time write locked in file btr0sea.cc line 1557
--Thread 140317670516480 has waited at btr0sea.cc line 934 for 0.00 seconds the semaphore:
S-lock on RW-latch at 0x55fd09116700 created in file btr0sea.cc line 243
a writer (thread id 140317647853312) has reserved it in mode  wait exclusive
number of readers 1, waiters flag 1, lock_word: ffffffff
Last time write locked in file btr0sea.cc line 1557
--Thread 140317639866112 has waited at btr0sea.cc line 934 for 0.00 seconds the semaphore:
S-lock on RW-latch at 0x55fd09116700 created in file btr0sea.cc line 243
a writer (thread id 140317647853312) has reserved it in mode  wait exclusive
number of readers 1, waiters flag 1, lock_word: ffffffff
Last time write locked in file btr0sea.cc line 1557
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 10122942
RW-shared spins 0, rounds 40759553, OS waits 237147
RW-excl spins 0, rounds 994262, OS waits 71533
RW-sx spins 220, rounds 1828, OS waits 40
Spin rounds per wait: 40759553.00 RW-shared, 994262.00 RW-excl, 8.31 RW-sx
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------

.......
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
10 queries inside InnoDB, 1 queries in queue
10 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=9541, Main thread ID=140317842663168, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 17731, updated 22665, deleted 12861, read 5275053684
2.00 inserts/s, 19.98 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 4063602.40 reads/s
Number of system rows inserted 0, updated 0, deleted 0, read 0
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

mysqltuner. Он рекомендует отключить кеш, но это не помогает. У CMS Битрикс много подзаропросов в запросах на которые из приложения особо не повлиять и с кешем работает быстрей.

```
-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Control warning line(s) into /var/log/mariadb/mysql_error.log file
    Control error line(s) into /var/log/mariadb/mysql_error.log file
    MySQL was started within the last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Increasing the query_cache size over 128M may reduce performance
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
    Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    query_cache_size (> 128M) [see warning above]
    join_buffer_size (> 512.0K, or always use indexes with JOINs)
```

Системные метрики за 12 часов. 
[image]

Статистика по использованию кеш mariadb за 12 часов. Я пробовал и отключать его - результат становился немного хуже. Кеш на этом проекте все же дает прирост производительности.

[image]

Статистика по типам запросов
[image]

[image]

Innidb метрики
[image]
[image]

По журналу медленных запросов я конечно сделал анализ, один из долгих запросов составляет порядка 80% медленных запросов, но его отключение не влияет на производительность и нагрузку на сервере.

А так выглядит мой atop последние несколько дней.
[image]

К сожалению расширенный мониторинг был настроен уже после проседания производительности и данных по серверу в лучшее его время нет.

Но по CPU график есть. 
[image]

**Буду благодарен за любую помощь или совет в поиске причин такого провала производительности.**

Comment: Ну а самое элементарное - температура на процах какая? Может просто пылью всё заросло, они перегреваются и происходит автоматическое снижение производительности....

Comment: Температура в норме

Physical id 0:  +47.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +43.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +42.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +47.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +45.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

Comment: Ещё один глупый вопрос: а Вы логи пытались смотреть? На картинке (Innidb метрики) показано, что каждый час в лог пишется по 128 мег почти. Это нормально?

Comment: Странность такую заметил. Если смотреть картинку "CPU Usage / Load" то видно, что больше всех ожидают процессы из-за *nice". Чего это огни вдруг решили дружно уступать приоритет?! Может у Вас что-то с приоритетами не то стало?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за помощь и советы!

Было сделано сразу две манипуляции способствующие решению проблемы. Какая из них решила проблему точно уже не скажу.

У Битрикс есть таблица с купонами скидок каталога, в ней у нас было 300 тыс. купонов. Так как изменить запрос нет возможности из-за его системности и обновления Битрикс все затрут, то были проведены тесты с данными. Удаление из таблицы 200 тыс. старых купонов позволило ускорить медленный запрос с ~1.3 сек. до 0.01 сек. В таблице осталось 60 тыс. купонов. 
Будем дорабатывать систему автоматической очистки купонов и писать обращение в Битрикс с просьбой оптимизации запроса. Хотя медленный запрос по данным мониторинга и отрабатывал ~3.7 раз в секунду, но это не мешало ему душить процессор.

Второе мероприятие это переход с mariadb (10.1, 10.3 - обе версии тестировались по несколько дней) на percona 8. Предположение пало на проблему базы данных с нашим набором данных и запросами, была мысль, а вдруг в перконе знаю и устранили ошибку.

Я все же полагаю, что ключевой фактор это медленный запрос. 
Видимо на наших данных этот запрос вызывал блокировки и высокую нагрузку на CPU из за повышения значений метрик RW Locks S OS Waits, RW Locks X OS Waits, RW Locks S Spin Rounds, RW Locks X Spin Rounds. Купонов становилось больше и в какой-то момент времени их кол. стало критичным для запроса.

Плавающий LA независящий от количества запросов к базе данных оказался влиянием вызова заданий по крону на выгрузку в яндекс маркет каталогов. Буду привязывать отображение заданий агентов Бирикс (крон задачи) на графиках, чтобы в будущем более явно строить связи нагрузки и работу приложения.

Comment: Slow log анализировали? Он ничего не показал? И как анализировали? Ни в вопросе, ни в ответе, про это ничего нет.

Comment: Анализировал и в вопрос и в ответе про это написал. Если подробней, то было выявлено 2 критически проблемных запроса. Первый был был связан с получением пользовательской сессии, которых у нас было уже больше 1 млн. только для гостей и второй по купонам. По первому в Битрикс направил решение по доработке метода API и они его приняли и скоро будет с ним обновление, второй еще в процессе исправления.

Comment: Да, невнимательно читал. `По журналу медленных запросов я конечно сделал анализ, один из долгих запросов составляет порядка 80% медленных запросов, но его отключение не влияет на производительность и нагрузку на сервере.`. Ерунда какая-то. Если по времени вышло 80%, а потом его "выключили", это время должно "освободиться". Как вы вышли на этот тормозной запрос, и как выключали? `pt-query-digest` использовали?

Comment: pt-query-digest не использовал, медленный запрос не составлял 80% всех запросов, из медленных запросов на него приходилось 80%. 2 запроса в секунду из 5 тыс. Не отключал т.к. это невозможно, удалили около 200 тыс. купонов, я в ответе это указал. По сессиям запрос сортировал 1 млн. записей и он выполнялся еще реже, но нагрузку на CPU порождал очень высокую.

Comment: Попробуйте `pt-query-digest`, он работает как монитор запросов (подключается к БД напрямую и делает что-то типа `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIT`), сбрасывая все это в файл дампа. Затем по этому дампу им можно снова пройтись, тогда эта утилита "суммирует" запросы и выводит время, потраченное на них. Очень мощный инструмент. Выглядит это примерно так: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/A-iAsoCCEAA-KlH.png

Comment: Благодарю за совет, буду пробовать. Пока мы для аналитики используем percona monitor manager, тоже хороший инструмент.